# Need to SELECT DISTINCT on one column in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring-boot

I have a table that I am trying to select distinct top 5 on the whole table, but return distinct by one column. Query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 [UserInteractionID]
,[LanID]
,[InteractionDttm]
,[SearchTypeName]
,[SearchTypeText]
FROM Config.UserInteraction
WHERE LanID=''
ORDER BY InteractionDttm DESC;
```

I am trying to get distinct values in the SearchTypeText column.

I am using this as a custom query in Spring Boot because I am getting an error using JPA/Hibernate

```
getDistinctTop5ByLanIDANDSearchTypeNameInOrderByInteractionDttmDesc(String lanID, String[] type)
```

Comment: can you share your Entity class.What error are you getting? And can you pass `List<String>` instead of `String[]`

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. You want the top 5 rows ordered by `InteractionDttm`? But while these five rows *can* contain five different `SearchTypeText`, they can also contain duplicates, e.g. twice one text and thrice another. And you want to do *what* in this situation? Please show sample data and its expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This query won't give you the desired result, This will return the distinct values of the complete row

for example for below row values

```
1,1,2,2
1,1,2,1
1,1,2,3
1,1,2,2
1,2,2,2
```

it will return

```
1,1,2,2
1,1,2,1
1,1,2,3
1,2,2,2
```

I hope it helps else please let me know and explain your question further. Thanks.